DBT testing for the source tables
I have a sources.yml which consists of all the source table that I need for the dbt.
version: 2
sources:
    - name: external
    schema: external_table
    tables:
      - name: event
      - name: mapping_table

I want to write dbt testing in tests_config.yml for these two tables, is it possible to do it?
Right now I have these in the tests_config.yml. However, when I try to run dbt test --select source:* it says nothing to do
version: 2

models:
  - name: event
    description:
    tests: 
      - dbt_utils.unique_combination_of_columns:
          combination_of_columns:
            - Event
            - State
            - financial_week_no
            - financial_year

Really appreciate the help! Thank you!

You need to place your tests in source.yml, then dbt will run these tests with dbt test --select source:*

Hi @Skylar, I have posted the above comment as a community wiki solution for the sake of community that might encounter this use case in the future. Do consider accepting and upvoting the answer, also feel free to edit the answer if required.

As commented by @Aleix CC, to resolve the issue, you need to place your tests in source.yml, then dbt will run these tests with dbt test --select source:*
Posting the answer as community wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future. Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.
